# How to change title of uitabBarItem either NIB file or prorammatically

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

Here is the line of code which is written in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but still uitabbar item title is not being changed.

[[self.userTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Your title"];

Where userTabBarController is

```
IBOutlet  UITabBarController *userTabBarController;
```

My tabbar has 3 tabs and these are conecting with 3 different viewController and it is loading fine.

Why title is not being set, code is seems to look ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [self.userTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] 

[viewController setTitle:@"Your title"];
```

Since that did not work for you I would suggest going to the implementation file of the view controller in your tabbarcontroller and simply doing:

```
self.title = @"my title";
```

in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Nope, it is not working. Where to write this line code, I mean in which function?

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar I would suggest then going to the ViewController implementation file and in the viewDidLoad do self.title = @"my title"

Comment: My first tab viewController name is homescreenvc and I wrote 'self.title = @"my title"; ' in the viewDidload but nothing happened, still I am not seeing title.Even I have put title for each tab in nib file also but is also not loading from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.userTabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

Comment: I wrote the above code in viewDidload but still nothing happened. Am I doing wrong from some other place setting or it is general issue? I searched every where and all code seems to look same.

Comment: debug and see if you see a valid address for tabBarItem. then on console type this (in debug mode): po tabBarItem.title and see what string it shows...

Comment: I found it is not calling either of viewDidload,viewDidAppear , viewWillAppear and awakeFromNib in the viewcontroller where selected tab belongs to. But XIB file is loading because designig coming well on screen.

Comment: great you found the solution. mark my answer if it helped you solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in NIB, .m file of your viewController..change your initWithNibName method like this.will work

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        [self setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aktuelles" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"News.png"] tag:0]];
        self.title = @"Aktuelles";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the title property of the view controller in its `awakeFromNib` method:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
   self.title = "My Title";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explore on the IB or if you want to set it not in the appdelegate file you can use this:

```
[[self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"new title 1"];
[[self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"new title 2"];
[[self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"new title 3"];
```

edit: coz it looks the same from the person who posted before me Xp

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITabBarItem *item = [self tabBarItem];
 item.title = @"Hi";
```